# How to customize Ilmenau beamer footer to print frame numbers

Tags: beamer, themes

I have googled this problem for hours and never found anything good for my need...

I love the `Ilmenau` theme with red `beaver` color, but I can not figure out how to manage settings for it...

Basically, I have several problems with this code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Ilmenau}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{pslatex}
\usecolortheme{beaver}

\title{My title}
\subtitle{My subtitle}
\institute{Fantastic school}
\date{\today}

\AtBeginSection[]
{
  \begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Table of Contents}
    \small \tableofcontents[currentsection, hideothersubsections]
  \end{frame}
}
\setcounter{framenumber}{0}

\begin{document}

{
\begin{frame}[plain]
\maketitle
\end{frame}
}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Table of Contents}
\tableofcontents 
\end{frame}

\section{First sections}

\subsection{Test one}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{My nice frametitle}
This is a text in first frame. This is a text in first frame. This is a text in first frame 
\end{frame}

\subsection{Test two}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{My second nice frametitle}
This is a text in second frame. This is a text in second frame. This is a text in second frame 
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

My questions are:

1. How to change color of "My fantastic School" displayed on every frame from white to black? (Well, actually it is not ... readable, we just can not see it!)
2. How to put some frame numbers at the extreme right of "My title"? I assume that I have to put `\insertframenumber/\inserttotalframenumber` somewhere, but... where exactly?
3. How to change the sillies blue rounded "1", "2" of `\tableofcontents` to something more cute ?

Thanks a lot for your help... Cheers!

Comment: Describe "more cute" more accurately, please. What would you like to use?

Comment: Anything else, I assume that it is always the same method to change that kind of details, right? So, let's say, "-" or simply numbers!

Comment: I see. Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You need to install the `institute in head/foot` color; for example:

   ```
   \setbeamercolor{institute in head/foot}{fg=black}
   ```
2. You need to redefine the `footline` template used by the `Ilmenau`; I marked the line were the change was made using `%<- here`.
3. You have several possible (all of them basic) modifications for the `sections/subsections in toc` allowing you to change the appearance of the sections and subsections in the ToC. See page 100 of the `beamer` manual to see the available options.

   For example, to suppress the markers (the numbers inside balls) you can say

   ```
   \setbeamertemplate{sections/subsections in toc}[default]
   ```

   If you want to make major customizations, you will have to redefine the templates `section in toc` and `subsection in toc`. In my example below I used a very basic design using an em-dash for sections and an en-dash for subsections:

   ```
   \defbeamertemplate*{section in toc}{mysections in toc}
   {\leavevmode ---\,\inserttocsection\par}

   \defbeamertemplate*{subsection in toc}{mysections in toc}
   {\leavevmode\leftskip=2.5em --\,\inserttocsubsection\par}
   ```

   but you can set them to be as cute as you widh.

The code contains comments:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Ilmenau}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usecolortheme{beaver}

%change color fot the institute
\setbeamercolor{institute in head/foot}{fg=black}
\makeatletter
%change the footline template to include frame numbers
\defbeamertemplate*{footline}{myminiframes theme}
  {%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=1.5pt]{upper separation line foot}
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,%
      leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm plus1fil]{author in head/foot}%
      \leavevmode{\usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertshortauthor}%
      \hfill%
      {\usebeamerfont{institute in head/foot}\usebeamercolor[fg]{institute in head/foot}\insertshortinstitute}%
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,%
      leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm plus1fil]{title in head/foot}%
      {\usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle\hfill \insertframenumber/\inserttotalframenumber}%<-here
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=1.5pt]{lower separation line foot}
    \end{beamercolorbox}
  }
\makeatother

%change look of sections in ToC
\defbeamertemplate*{section in toc}{mysections in toc}
{\leavevmode ---\,\inserttocsection\par}

%change look of subsections in ToC
\defbeamertemplate*{subsection in toc}{mysections in toc}
{\leavevmode\leftskip=2.5em --\,\inserttocsubsection\par}

\title{My title}
\subtitle{My subtitle}
\institute{Fantastic school}
\date{\today}

\AtBeginSection[]
{
  \begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Table of Contents}
    \small \tableofcontents[currentsection, hideothersubsections]
  \end{frame}
}
\setcounter{framenumber}{0}

\begin{document}

{
\begin{frame}[plain]
\maketitle
\end{frame}
}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Table of Contents}
\tableofcontents 
\end{frame}

\section{First sections}

\subsection{Test one}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{My nice frametitle}
This is a text in first frame. This is a text in first frame. This is a text in first frame 
\end{frame}

\subsection{Test two}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{My second nice frametitle}
This is a text in second frame. This is a text in second frame. This is a text in second frame 
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]